# How can I get rid of Android Is Starting Optimising App, On A Chinese Phone?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

From time to time I get the "Android Is Starting Optimising App"  message.

I understand that there might be an option to reset it

My phone is like the one in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skyjFQERMQM

[image]

I did get this menu up on my phone.

That video shows a factory reset though(which you get choosing the eMMC option), but I don't want to do a factory reset, I don't want to wipe everything off my phone every time I get this message!

I heard there might be a cache of some kind that is safe to delete, that would remove that message, but I can't see the option to delete that.

If I go to settings..about, it says  DOOGEE-Y6C-Android6.0-2017015

It started doing this after some kind of update that I think happened automatically.

Comment: What's wrong with the optimization? Are you stuck there? Old versions of Android used to optimize apps after every system update. So, all looks normal to me here.

Comment: @singhnsk  A)It can take 20min sometimes even when it's only 1  app to 'optimise'. B) It can happen any time, like twice in one day, i'm worried about powering my phone off because if I get in my car to make a journey and power it on so as to use google maps, it may take my phone 20min at that screen.   If i'm in  a shop that is  to close in 10min, and I power up my phone to check something, the shop will be closed by the time it is up.  Often I need to use my phone within a minute or two of turning it on.      Also, mention old versions of android..Do I have an old version of android?

Comment: if I have an old version of android, why would my phone have updated to an old version of android?

Comment: Okay. So, it is happening randomly even without a phone system update? In that case, it is a good chance that your device is suffering from some sort of hardware issue. You can try doing a factory reset, but I doubt that's going to solve it.

Comment: @singhnsk  I think you're jumping to conclusions re hardware, but even if it were, there may be  there is some cache that can be cleared i've done it before from the shell(though not for this problem).  dalvik cache or something .. maybe if I get an english boot loader I can clear that cache easily, if it will help workaround that